# Project structure is different from before: modules are under src folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I used to create java project this way:

In terminal:

1)Create a workspace called ProjectA;

From IntelliJ:

1)File -> New -> Project from existing sources...

2)select ProjectA;

3)add new modules;

4)in terminal: all modules are under ProjectA/src/

Then, if I select Project on the top left of IntelliJ, all modules will show up. For example:

Project

- ModuleA
- ModuleB
- ModuleC
- ModuleD

But I don't know what I did yesterday, and the structure looks like below:

Project

ProjectA

src

- ModuleA
- ModuleB
- ModuleC
- ModuleD

How can I change the structure back? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you changed the project display to "Project Files" in the upper left corner ? I think the original one was "Project".

Comment: One strange thing is that: for this project, if I select "Project Files", it displays all modules directly, and if I select "Project", it displays Project name, src, then all modules. However, for all other projects I created, if I select Project, it displays modules directly.